# JSF tag not rendering after migrating the application to WAS 7

Tags: jsf, websphere-7, ibm-jsf

I have been working on migration or JSF application from WAS 6.1 to 7. The application uses JSF 1.1. I made the following changes in `web.xml` to make the code compatible with JSF 1.1 as per the forums I referred.

```xml
<!--  Added for the compatibility with JSF 1.1 on WAS7 -->
<context-param>  
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>    
    <param-value>true</param-value>  
</context-param>    

<!-- Removed for JSF 1.1 compatibility on WAS 7
<listener>
    <listener-class> com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
-->
```

However, there are some pages which contains `<hx:jspPanel>` and other `hx` components, but those doesn't render correctly. It appears as

```
!!jsftagmarker!!!!jsftagmarker!! !!jsftagmarker!!!!jsftagmarker!!
```

Could you please advise how this issue can be resolved? Do I need to upgrade to JSF 1.2 or JSF 2.0 to resolve the issue? Is it possible to resolve the issue without upgrading JSF?

Comment: The `hx` components are from IBM Faces Client Framework which is indeed part of WAS 5.x and 6.x. I've never really worked with WAS 7.x or newer, but it look like that it don't contain the IBM Faces Client Framework, or a different version. Perhaps you need to migrate those `hx` tags as well.

Comment: Thanks BalusC! Actally I looked for the tags providing the similar functionality in JSF standard library (h: tags), but no luck. Could you please advise on migrating these hx components?

Comment: I also tried putting the jsf-ibm jar in lib folder and changed the classloader to PARENT_LAST. but no luck.

Comment: Any inputs on this, please?

Comment: I'd try IBM developer network forums.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

basically jsf12 is the requirement here. The similar problem i saw which is posted over 6 years ago with WAS7 and jsf1.1 https://coderanch.com/t/609870/java/hx-jspPanel-rendering gives hint that issues needs a configuration changes.

Here are configuration changes in your webshpere cell:

1. For the application (Enterprise Applications > mywebapp > Shared library references)create a shared library reference say jsf12
2. Environment -> shared libraries - define jsf12 by defining its calsspath, native library path correctly

Now, it should help to pick up the new library and make this tag work well.

if you are having multiple applications depending on different versions keep the checkbox Use an isolated class loader for this shared library

Comment: also check from class loader are these newly defined shared libraries are getting loaded in the order that you are expecting